# Php + ajax комментарии

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Подскажите в какую сторону копать, хочу сделать свою систему комментирования на сайте, сразу скажу что я новичок в программировании. Текущая задача такая, есть список комментариев, у каждого из них есть кнопка ответить, при клике на неё должно под тем комментарием где была кликнута кнопка появится форма для добавления комментария. Вот такая банальная задача вызвала затруднение. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Comment: А, может, проще подключить готовую? Тот же [disqus][1] Сомневаюсь, что вам тут будут приводить полные листинги рабочего кода для реализации подобного.

 [1]: http://disqus.com/

Comment: Посмотрите здесь пример, только вот с подгрузкой немного "непонятки" https://toster.ru/q/7550